# Having difficultyin parsing xml in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an XML similar to one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Entities>
    <Entity>
        <Entity_Sequence>1</Entity_Sequence>
        <Entity_Schema_Name>XYZ</Entity_Schema_Name>
        <Entity_ID>839674039</Entity_ID>
        <Entity_Name>EntName1</Entity_Name>
        <Entity_Type>1</Entity_Type>
        <Entity_Alias>X</Entity_Alias>
        <Entity_ID>839674039</Entity_ID>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute>
                <Attribute_Sequence>1</Attribute_Sequence>
                <Attribute_Name>Attr1</Attribute_Name>
                <Filter_Operator>24002</Filter_Operator>
                <Filter_Value>12</Filter_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Attribute_Sequence>2</Attribute_Sequence>
                <Attribute_Name>2</Attribute_Name>
                <Filter_Operator>24001</Filter_Operator>
                <Filter_Value>22</Filter_Value>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Entity>
</Entities>
```

I tried but I either get the outer nested xml or the inner  one.
Is it possible to use t-sql to get values like below:

[image]

Comment: You have no Attribute_ID in the nested values but you are expecting some value Nesting_Predicate_Attribute_ID. Where would you get that from?

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Basically, I want to repeat the parent in each row along with the child elements.

Comment: Is it possible to do a third cross apply here in case we had one more hierarchy ?

Comment: I hope you have tried it out until now and found out that yes, you can do that. :)

Comment: No, I tired a few times and then gave up for lack of time. Could you please post a sample for a third level ? Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
   a.b.value('Entity_Sequence[1]','varchar(10)') AS Entity_Sequence,
   a.b.value('Entity_Schema_Name[1]','varchar(10)') AS Entity_Schema_Name,
   a.b.value('Entity_ID[1]','varchar(10)') AS Entity_ID,
   a.b.value('Entity_Name[1]','varchar(10)') AS Entity_Name,
   a.b.value('Entity_Type[1]','varchar(10)') AS Entity_Type,
   a.b.value('Entity_Alias[1]','varchar(10)') AS Entity_Alias,
   tab.col.value('Attribute_Sequence[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Attribute_Sequence,
   tab.col.value('Attribute_Name[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Attribute_Name,
   tab.col.value('Filter_Operator[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Filter_Operator,
   tab.col.value('Filter_Value[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Filter_Value    
FROM @MyXML.nodes('/Entities/Entity') a(b) cross apply a.b.nodes('Attributes/Attribute') as tab(col)
```

I am reading the Entity values from the main xml and then using `CROSS APPLY` at the Attribute node for getting the nested xml values.

You can check a working version of this [here](http://rextester.com/IFYMK16724).

Comment: Haha! You beat me by one minute! We came up with almost identical solutions... for performance optimization you want to include the text() node reference when pulling text.

Answer (score 1):

Using the information you provided (note that your screenshot does not match your data:

```
DECLARE @yourxml XML=
'<Entities>
    <Entity>
        <Entity_Sequence>1</Entity_Sequence>
        <Entity_Schema_Name>XYZ</Entity_Schema_Name>
        <Entity_ID>839674039</Entity_ID>
        <Entity_Name>EntName1</Entity_Name>
        <Entity_Type>1</Entity_Type>
        <Entity_Alias>X</Entity_Alias>
        <Entity_ID>839674039</Entity_ID>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute>
                <Attribute_Sequence>1</Attribute_Sequence>
                <Attribute_Name>Attr1</Attribute_Name>
                <Filter_Operator>24002</Filter_Operator>
                <Filter_Value>12</Filter_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
                <Attribute_Sequence>2</Attribute_Sequence>
                <Attribute_Name>2</Attribute_Name>
                <Filter_Operator>24001</Filter_Operator>
                <Filter_Value>22</Filter_Value>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Entity>
</Entities>'

SELECT 
 Entity_Sequence    = ent.e.value('(Entity_Sequence/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 Entity_Schema_Name = ent.e.value('(Entity_Schema_Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 [Entity_ID]        = ent.e.value('(Entity_ID/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 [Entity_Name]      = ent.e.value('(Entity_Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 Entity_Type        = ent.e.value('(Entity_Type/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 Entity_Alias       = ent.e.value('(Entity_Alias/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 Attribute_Sequence = att.a.value('(Attribute_Sequence/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 Attribute_Name     = att.a.value('(Attribute_Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 Filter_Operator    = att.a.value('(Filter_Operator/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
 Filter_Value       = att.a.value('(Filter_Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM (VALUES (@yourxml)) t(x)
CROSS APPLY t.x.nodes('Entities/Entity') ent(e)
CROSS APPLY ent.e.nodes('Attributes/Attribute') att(a);
```

Results:

```
Entity_Sequence Entity_Schema_Name Entity_ID  Entity_Name Entity_Type Entity_Alias Attribute_Sequence Attribute_Name Filter_Operator Filter_Value
--------------- ------------------ ---------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------------------ -------------- --------------- ------------
1               XYZ                839674039  EntName1    1           X            1                  Attr1          24002           12
1               XYZ                839674039  EntName1    1           X            2                  2              24001           22
```